# Don't show "more" when showing current configuration on Cisco Nexus switch

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

How do you stop a Cisco Nexus 3000 series switch from paging (i.e. showing "more" and forcing the user to hit space/enter) before doing a `show running`?

On a Cisco ASA, you can do "term pager 0", but that specific syntax doesn't seem to work on a Nexus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`terminal length 0` should be all you need to do this.

From the NX-OS CLI Navigator
http://www.cisco.com/web/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/nxos/commands/fund/terminal_length.html

Comment: +1. works also for IOS.